# how to run ansible playbook in aws lambda function

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ansible

I was trying the below link method where i have uploaded the zip file to lambda function and by passing parameters executed the lambda. That throws error as follow.
  Please suggest me how to solve this , how i can run lambda with playbook

[[1]: https://medium.com/@jacoelho/ansible-in-aws-lambda-980bb8b5791b](https://medium.com/@jacoelho/ansible-in-aws-lambda-980bb8b5791b)

```
START RequestId: 9c140646-5a3c-430b-81cf-458aaa7cdd77 Version: $LATEST
module initialization error: Invalid settings supplied for DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP: Unable to create local directories(/home/sbx_user1051/.ansible/tmp):

 [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/ansible/config/manager.py",

 line 489, in update_config_data
    value, origin = self.get_config_value_and_origin(config, configfile)
  File "/var/task/ansible/config/manager.py",

 line 434, in get_config_value_and_origin
    value = ensure_type(value, defs[config].get('type'), origin=origin)
  File "/var/task/ansible/config/manager.py", 

line 91, in ensure_type
    makedirs_safe(value, 0o700)
  File "/var/task/ansible/utils/path.py",

 line 81, in makedirs_safe
    raise AnsibleError("Unable to create local directories(%s): %s" % (to_native(rpath), to_native(e)))
AnsibleError: Unable to create local directories(/home/sbx_user1051/.ansible/tmp): [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'

END RequestId: 9c140646-5a3c-430b-81cf-458aaa7cdd77
REPORT RequestId: 9c140646-5a3c-430b-81cf-458aaa7cdd77  Duration: 45.12 ms  Billed Duration: 100 ms     Memory Size: 1472 MB    Max Memory Used: 65 MB  
module initialization error
Invalid settings supplied for DEFAULT_LOCAL_TMP: Unable to create local directories(/home/sbx_user1051/.ansible/tmp): [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/ansible/config/manager.py",

 line 489, in update_config_data
    value, origin = self.get_config_value_and_origin(config, configfile)
  File "/var/task/ansible/config/manager.py",

 line 434, in get_config_value_and_origin
    value = ensure_type(value, defs[config].get('type'), origin=origin)
  File "/var/task/ansible/config/manager.py", 

line 91, in ensure_type
    makedirs_safe(value, 0o700)
  File "/var/task/ansible/utils/path.py", 

line 81, in makedirs_safe
    raise AnsibleError("Unable to create local directories(%s): %s" % (to_native(rpath), to_native(e)))

AnsibleError: Unable to create local directories(/home/sbx_user1051/.ansible/tmp): [Errno 30] Read-only file system: '/home/sbx_user1051'
```

Comment: what is the version on the ansible you have installed ? There might be some issue with the version and is resolved with the fix in the version specified in the below URL. https://review.openstack.org/#/c/577544

Comment: I am using  ansible 2.7.8 version

Answer (score 1):

You did not change the temp directory as indicated in the post:

```
# use /tmp instead of $HOME
ansible.constants.DEFAULT_REMOTE_TMP = '/tmp/ansible'
```